# How to add Project Dependency using gradle?

Tags: gradle

I am facing the following problem. I need to build the multi-project, but when I try to add the dependency I got the following error.

**Root Project's settings.gradle:**

```
include 'DbServices','HelloWeb'
```

**Root Project's build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
project(':HelloWeb') {
   dependencies {
      compile (':DbServices')   
   }
}
```

**DbServices's build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

**HelloWeb's build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

However, then I am getting the following error when synchronize with the gradle tasks on Root Project:

> Executing command: "tasks"

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\MyDeployment\RootProject\build.gradle' line: 21
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating root project 'RootProject'.

  > Could not find method compile() for arguments [:DbServices] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@3b3e3b3e.
- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'RootProject'.

Answer (score 11):

[The documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#javadependencies_1) uses the following syntax:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':DbServices')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The notion of `compile` dependencies is introduced by the `java` plugin. Therefore, this plugin has to be applied (to the HelloWeb project) *before* declaring dependencies. The easiest way to fix this is to move the `dependencies` block into HelloWeb's `build.gradle`. Additionally, the project dependency syntax needs to be fixed according to JB Nizet's answer.